# divs or tables for complex layout?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have researched and read a lot about pros and cons on extensive uses of divs or tables.

And my understanding in nutshell is that tables are only good for tabular data and is old fashion.

Whereas div allows more flexibility and is faster to maintain, load, and to implement for responsive design.

**I get confused when some people say:**

-extensive use of divs or deeply nested divs are bad practice

-extensive use of tables for everything that could be achieved by using divs and css are not recommended

**(1) So my question is: which is best recommended to use to achieve this two layouts ?**
(knowing that I will make them responsive later)

Image 1 "this week":

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy5XG.png]

Image 2 "this month":

[image: http://www.bayeast.org/stackoverflow/layout2.png]

(2) **My second question is if it recommended to use divs to achieve it, how would you proceed ?**  since it a very complex layout and I only tables as a solution without using extensive amount of divs or deeply nested divs.

Thank you for your help

Here is my code for this week: (knowing the mouseover should highlight in blue the entire row)

**HTML code**

```
<div id="thisWeek" class="box">
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/calendar.jpg" /></td><td valign="middle"><span style="font-size:16px;">This Week</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<ul class="engage">
<li><a href="">Add</a></li>
<li><a href="">More</a></li>
</ul>
<table id="thisWeekTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td class="select"><div class="checkbox"><input id="checkboxInput" type="checkbox" name="" value="1"><label for="checkboxInput"></label></div></td><td><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">02</p> <p style="font-size:10px;">Sept</p></td><td width="100%">&nbsp; Zipform 6 basics</td></tr>
<tr><td class="select"><div class="checkbox"><input id="checkboxInput2" type="checkbox" name="" value="2"><label for="checkboxInput2"></label></div></td><td><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">13</p> <p style="font-size:10px;">Jan</p></td><td width="100%">&nbsp; Training on Paragon</td></tr>
<tr><td class="select"><div class="checkbox"><input id="checkboxInput3" type="checkbox" name="" value="1"><label for="checkboxInput3"></label></div></td><td><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">26</p> <p style="font-size:10px;">Feb</p></td><td width="100%">&nbsp; Planing and Goals</td></tr>
<tr><td class="select"><div class="checkbox"><input id="checkboxInput4" type="checkbox" name="" value="1"><label for="checkboxInput4"></label></div></td><td><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">11</p> <p style="font-size:10px;">Mar</p></td><td width="100%">&nbsp; Zipform 6 basics</td></tr>
<tr><td class="select"><div class="checkbox"><input id="checkboxInput5" type="checkbox" name="" value="1"><label for="checkboxInput5"></label></div></td><td><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">09</p> <p style="font-size:10px;">Nov</p></td><td width="100%">&nbsp; Training on Paragon</td></tr>
<tr><td class="select"><div class="checkbox"><input id="checkboxInput6" type="checkbox" name="" value="1"><label for="checkboxInput6"></label></div></td><td><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">26</p> <p style="font-size:10px;">Feb</p></td><td width="100%">&nbsp; Planing and Goals</td></tr>

</table>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.box { 
    position:relative;
    width:282px;
    height:240px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    color:#808080;
}

.engage { 
    float:right;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:-35px;
}

.engage li { 
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-right:-5px;
}

.engage li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#808080;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-right:-5px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}

.engage li a:hover { 
    background-color:#C9C9C9;
    color:#fff;
}

#thisWeek {
    width:220px;
}

#thisWeekTable p {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
}

.select {
    width:60px;
    padding-left:20px;
}

.checkbox {
    width: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.checkbox label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    border: 3px solid #808080;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checkbox label:hover::after {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}


#thisWeekTable tr:hover { 
    background-color:#7FC1E2;
    color:#fff;
}
```

And here is the code for the second "this month"

**HTML code**

```
<p>This month:</p>

<table class="classSchedule" width="100%">
<tr class="tableSection">
<td class="color" rowspan="2"></td><td class="date" rowspan="2"><ul><li>mon</li><li class="dayNum">30</li></ul></td><td class="class" colspan="2">CCIM: Financial Tools for Commercial Real Estate </td><td class="classAddCal" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href=""><img src="images/classAddCal.png"/></a></td><td class="classAction" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classArrow.png"/></a><a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classExpanded.png" alt="arrow"/></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$</td><td><img src="images/view.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" class="actionList">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><div class="classWatchButton">Watch</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classMoreButton">Learn more</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classRegisterButton">Register</div></a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="classSchedule" width="100%">
<tr class="tableSection">
<td class="color" rowspan="2"></td><td class="date" rowspan="2"><ul><li>mon</li><li class="dayNum">30</li></ul></td><td class="class" colspan="2">CCIM: Financial Tools for Commercial Real Estate </td><td class="classAddCal" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href=""><img src="images/classAddCal.png"/></a></td><td class="classAction" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classArrow.png"/></a><a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classExpanded.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$</td><td><img src="images/view.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" class="actionList">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><div class="classWatchButton">Watch</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classMoreButton">Learn more</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classRegisterButton">Register</div></a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="classSchedule" width="100%">
<tr class="tableSection">
<td class="color" rowspan="2"></td><td class="date" rowspan="2"><ul><li>mon</li><li class="dayNum">30</li></ul></td><td class="class" colspan="2">CCIM: Financial Tools for Commercial Real Estate </td><td class="classAddCal" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href=""><img src="images/classAddCal.png"/></a></td><td class="classAction" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classArrow.png"/></a><a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classExpanded.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$</td><td><img src="images/view.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" class="actionList" id="1">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><div class="classWatchButton">Watch</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classMoreButton">Learn more</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classRegisterButton">Register</div></a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="classSchedule" width="100%">
<tr class="tableSection">
<td class="color" rowspan="2"></td><td class="date" rowspan="2"><ul><li>mon</li><li class="dayNum">30</li></ul></td><td class="class" colspan="2">CCIM: Financial Tools for Commercial Real Estate </td><td class="classAddCal" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href=""><img src="images/classAddCal.png"/></a></td><td class="classAction" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classArrow.png"/></a><a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classExpanded.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$</td><td><img src="images/view.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" class="actionList" id="2">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><div class="classWatchButton">Watch</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classMoreButton">Learn more</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classRegisterButton">Register</div></a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="classSchedule" width="100%">
<tr class="tableSection">
<td class="color" rowspan="2"></td><td class="date" rowspan="2"><ul><li>mon</li><li class="dayNum">30</li></ul></td><td class="class" colspan="2">CCIM: Financial Tools for Commercial Real Estate </td><td class="classAddCal" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href=""><img src="images/classAddCal.png"/></a></td><td class="classAction" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classArrow.png"/></a><a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classExpanded.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$</td><td><img src="images/view.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" class="actionList">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><div class="classWatchButton">Watch</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classMoreButton">Learn more</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classRegisterButton">Register</div></a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="classSchedule" width="100%">
<tr class="tableSection">
<td class="color" rowspan="2"></td><td class="date" rowspan="2"><ul><li>mon</li><li class="dayNum">25</li></ul></td><td class="class" colspan="2">CCIM: Financial Tools for Commercial Real Estate </td><td class="classAddCal" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href=""><img src="images/classAddCal.png"/></a></td><td class="classAction" rowspan="2" align="right"><a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classArrow.png"/></a><a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1"><img class="actionCol" src="images/classExpanded.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$</td><td><img src="images/view.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" class="actionList">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><div class="classWatchButton">Watch</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classMoreButton">Learn more</div></a></li>
<li><a href=""><div class="classRegisterButton">Register</div></a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS code**

```
#classBanner {
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(../images/classbanner.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:799px;
    height:532px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:-25px;
}

#classCont {
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    width:411px;
    height:437px;
    left:10px;
    font-size:18px;
}

#classCont p {
    font-size:25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#calIcon {
    width:162px;
    height:79px;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:40px;
}

#calIcon img { 
    margin-top:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#calIcon a { 
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}

#calIcon a:hover { 
    background-color:#666;
}

#classScheduleDiv {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    color:#4D4D4D;
    right:35px;
    bottom:0;
    width:250px;
    height:425px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

.color {
    background-color:#F90;
    width:2px;
    height:100%;
}

.classRegisterButton {
    background-color:#29A5DC;
    color:#fff;
    max-width:65px;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; /* Safari & Chrome */
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;/* Firefox */
        -ms-border-radius: 4px;/* Internet Explorer */
         -o-border-radius: 4px;/* Opera */
             border-radius: 4px;
}


.classMoreButton {
    background-color:#C6C6C6;
    color:#333333;
    max-width:65px;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; /* Safari & Chrome */
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;/* Firefox */
        -ms-border-radius: 4px;/* Internet Explorer */
         -o-border-radius: 4px;/* Opera */
             border-radius: 4px;
}

.classWatchButton {
    background-color:#C6C6C6;
    color:#333333;
    max-width:65px;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; /* Safari & Chrome */
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;/* Firefox */
        -ms-border-radius: 4px;/* Internet Explorer */
         -o-border-radius: 4px;/* Opera */
             border-radius: 4px;
}

.date ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.date ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.dayNum {
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.actionList ul {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.actionList ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}

table.classSchedule { 
    border-top:1px solid #ADADAD;
}

.show {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target + .show {
    display: inline; 
}
.hide:target {
    display: none; 
}

td.actionList {
    display: none;
}

.hide:target ~ td.actionList {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Tables aren't for layouts, period.

Comment: @Diodeus thank you for clarification, any idea on how to achieve the same effects with divs ?
JSFIDDLE 1: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bayeast/WLyd8/)
JSFIDDLE 2: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bayeast/NLJ62/)

Comment: You can use unordered lists with floats in each LI. See this for a starter: http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: @bayeast using CSS you can position things however you like. You can use floats and margins to achieve what you want if you need older browser support, otherwise flex box is an incredibly useful tool to be able to use.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap is also a good place to start. Look at their PANELS implementation.

Comment: @Diodeus thanks for the article it is useful, that's the problem I have been trained on using tables for creating forms, but it is a "semantic faux pas" as the article states.

Comment: After looking at the images that you added to your post, they actually do look somewhat like tabular data, you could probably use a table on them and not break semantic meaning. Just don't use them for layouts. For example, using tables to position the whole element on the page would be a horrible idea.

Comment: @sage88 started to check out flex box thanks for the tips

Comment: @Diodeus have been hesitant to use bootstrap since you find different opinion on the net knowing that I am creating a wordpress site for a company that have 6000 users. I am afraid of bootstrap overloading the site resulting in poor speed and efficiency. so what is your take on that?

Comment: Bootstrap is CSS. It's used by sites with millions of users. It has nothing to do with performance. It's about HTML patterns and applied styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use tables for layouts. They have a semantic meaning and should not be used for that purpose. Divs should be used for layout design, but the key is to not over using them (or heavily nesting them as you mentioned). You need to learn how to position elements without overly relying on divs to reach this. You can also give your layout better semantic meaning my using the new HTML5 block level elements. These include section, article, and nav which can be used just like divs, but they mean something about what content should be included there.

As far as keeping your layouts simple, you might want to look at flex box which is an incredibly powerful positioning tool of CSS3. If you do go with flex box, just be aware of its limitations: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Just to give you an example of how you could do this, here's the HTML markup you have now:

```
<tr>
    <td class="select">
        <div class="checkbox">
             <input id="checkboxInput6" type="checkbox" name="" value="1">
             <label for="checkboxInput6"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">26</p>
        <p style="font-size:10px;">Feb</p>
    </td>
    <td width="100%">
        &nbsp; Planing and Goals
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's how I would leave the markup if I were using tables to do this which I don't think is inappropriate given the type of data:

```
<tr>
    <td class="select">
        <input class="week-checkbox" id="checkboxInput6" type="checkbox" value="1">
        <label class="week-checkbox" for="checkboxInput6"></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="week-day">26</p>
        <p class="week-month">Feb</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="week-topic">Planing and Goals</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is enough markup to use CSS and style it exactly as you have now. It removes all of the unnecessary markup and keeps styling information in a separate document so you don't need to repeat it constantly. The div that you used to position your checkbox is an example of over-using divs. It's completely unnecessary there, you could position without it and it doesn't make semantic sense. It's a problem called divitis and you aren't the only one to suffer it, feel free to look up some articles about it so that you get some hints on how to work around it.

If you wanted to do the same thing only using an unordered list, I would do it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="week-select">
        <input class="week-checkbox" id="checkboxInput6" type="checkbox" value="1">
        <label class="week-checkbox" for="checkboxInput6"></label>
        <p><span class="week-day">26</span><span class="week-month">Feb</span></p>
        <p class="week-topic">Planing and Goals</p>
    </li>
...
</ul>
```

And then you'd need to construct CSS to position these elements as needed. That said, there's enough markup here to be able to produce the same layout. The goal of good markup is to keep it meaningful and simple. Too much positional markup ruins the meaning and becomes difficult to understand.

Comment: @bayeast Added an example to give you some ideas on how to simplify your markup.

Comment: "Never use tables for layouts" **Unless showing tabular data in which case a <table> would be the correct and semantic way to go.**

Comment: @Paulie_D but then it's tabular data and not a layout :), but I agree and if you read my comment above I mention that his example is actually tabular data and is therefore appropriate for use in a table.

Comment: @sage88 you are right thanks for the examples and ideas. I will rewrite the pages with a simpler markup as advised

Comment: @sage88 just to make sure, you say that in this case it will be fine to work with tables in this example ?

Comment: @bayeast Yes, this is quasi-tabular data and is ok for use in a table. It would probably be better in an unordered list, but isn't inappropriate for use in a table. What you don't want to do is make an entire layout using tables. So each one of the elements you showed would be a table, but don't use tables to position them on the page.